# Getting wrong output with Java arithmetic

Tags: java, int, double

I guess this is a very simple task, but since I'm new to java i find this pretty difficult. I keep getting -1 all the time, but when I compile it the output is: 1. Could anyone explain me why and how the output is: 1. Thanks

```
class Test {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        double x = 3.14; //3.14
        int m = (int) (x-5); //3.14 - 5 = -1.83 --> (int )-1 
        int k = m + m * m -m; // -1 + (-1*-1) - 1 --> -1???
        System.out.println(k); // -1??

    }
}
```

Comment: Well have you tried debugging through it? Checking the value of m?

Comment: `-1 + (-1*-1) - (-1)`

Comment: Your interpretation of `-1 + (-1*-1) - 1` should be `-1 + (-1*-1) - (-1)`

Comment: `puclic` should also be `public`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line is a given:

```
double x = 3.14; //3.14
```

The second line is truncating the result of the subtraction:

```
int m = (int) (x-5); //3.14 - 5 = -1.83 --> -1
```

At this point, it's just math. Don't forget that subtracting a negative number is the same as adding it's absolute value:

```
int k = m + m * m -m; // -1 + (-1*-1) - 1 --> -1 + 1 - (-1) --> 0 - (-1) --> 1
```

1. -1 + (-1 * -1) - (-1)
2. -1 + 1 + 1
3. 0 + 1
4. 1

Answer (score 1):

-1 + (-1*-1) - (-1) = 1.  You forgot to subtract the negative.